# Why there is a "strike" in my typescript code?

Tags: typescript

As my first attempt to convert javascript into typescript, I realize that there are some code being strike out. May I know the reason of that strike and what is the meaning of those strike? What should I do about it? Here is the screenshot as example. I'm using visual studio code

[image]

Comment: Those are usually deprecated functions. Depending on the functions, there might be alternative you can use.

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I *suspect* it means that member is being deprecated and is advising you to use a newer alternative.  For example, using `.on()` for binding event handlers in jQuery.

Comment: Put the mouse cursor on top of the words and see what the popup says (assuming this is VSCode.)

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a feature of the editor you re using.
It shows you that these functions are `deprecated` and you shouldn't use them.